# Make the logo transparent in Python tkinter 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to insert an icon in my GUI. I have already tried inserting one but I need help and want to make it **transparent**. Can I make the icon transparent in any way? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've voted to close this question as a duplicate; in the meantime, here is working code for what the first answer was trying to do:

**Python 2.x**:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import Tkinter
import tempfile
import base64
import zlib

ICON = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJxjYGAEQgEBBiDJwZDBy'
    'sAgxsDAoAHEQCEGBQaIOAg4sDIgACMUj4JRMApGwQgF/ykEAFXxQRc='))

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

tk = Tkinter.Tk()
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = Tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
import tkinter
import tempfile
import base64
import zlib

ICON = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('eJxjYGAEQgEBBiDJwZDBy'
    'sAgxsDAoAHEQCEGBQaIOAg4sDIgACMUj4JRMApGwQgF/ykEAFXxQRc='))

_, ICON_PATH = tempfile.mkstemp()
with open(ICON_PATH, 'wb') as icon_file:
    icon_file.write(ICON)

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.iconbitmap(default=ICON_PATH)
label = tkinter.Label(tk, text="Window with transparent icon.")
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tkinter, you can use **Python 3:** `tkinter.iconbitmap(yourIconFilePath)` **Python 2:** `Tkinter.iconbitmap(yourIconFilePath)`

**NOTE:** Icon files have the *.ico extension